# C++ - Cannot return vector from function

Tags: c++, function, vector, return

Assume the following function

```
std::vector<double> LocatePulseEdges(int points, double* signal_x, double* signal_y, double threshold, vector<double> left_edge, vector<double> right_edge){
cout << "1" << endl;
    for (int i=0; i<points; i++){
        if(signal_y[i]<threshold){// left side of the pulse
            left_edge.push_back(signal_x[i]);
            break;
        }
        if(signal_y[i]>threshold){// right side of the pulse
            right_edge.push_back(signal_x[i]);
            break;
        }
    }
cout << "6" << endl;
    return left_edge;
    //return right_edge;

cout << "7" << endl;
}
```

I am calling this function in the following code

```
void Analyze(){
    int points = 90000000;//hSignal->GetNbinsX();
    double* x          = new double[points];           // SIZE limited only by OS/Hardware
    double* y          = new double[points];
    std::vector<double> left;
    std::vector<double> right;
    double threshold = 6234.34;

    Function_to_Fill_X_and_Y();
    LocatePulseEdges(points, x, y, threshold, left, right);
    cout << "First left threshold crossing @ time : " << left[0] << endl;
}
```

Although I get no compilation error, when I run the program, it crashes right before the return statement.

Any idea on why this is happening?

Comment: @Boiethios : Hmmm... How can I check that? And if this the case, how can I solve it?

Comment: sorry, it is not that I guess.

Comment: @Thanos Why do you pass vectors by value?

Comment: @GMichael : What else can I do? I am not that familiar with pointers... :(

Comment: @Thanos read about reference...

Comment: @Thanos Pass them by reference. No pointers involved :-)

Comment: @GMichael Thanks for the advice! How can I do that?

Comment: `std::vector<double>& LocatePulseEdges(int points, double* signal_x, double* signal_y, double threshold, vector<double>& left_edge, vector<double>& right_edge)`  And remove the return statement. You do not need it in this case

Comment: @GMichael : I tried this, but still my program crushes right before the `return` statement...

Comment: @Thanos Remove the return. You do not need it now.

Comment: @GMichael : Now it's working, but when I call `left_edge[0]` in the program, it crushes again...

Comment: Why so many downvotes? OP provides code, and a clearly written question....Just don't get it :O   If someone think the OP is dumb or what, you can just post an answer. But the question itself is perfectly fine to me :/

Comment: @shole Thank you so much for your support!

Comment: @Thanos Make sure `left_edge` is not empty before accessing its members

Comment: @GMichael : How to do that? In principle it supposed to be filled from the function `LocatePulseEdges()` right?

Comment: @Thanos First, `left_edge` is filled if `if(signal_y[i]<threshold)` only. If for any reason it did not happened, the vector is empty. So, `std::vector::empty()` is your friend: `if(!left_edge.empty()) cout<< left_edge[0];`

Comment: @GMichael you should make sure not only if vector is empty, but also if vector contains given index, so `.size() <= index` is better than `.empty()`

Comment: @MaciekGrynda You are correct in general, but the code above prints `left_edge[0]`.  So, test for emptyness is enough in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several flaws in the `LocatePulseEdges` function, as well as the `Analyze` function.

First, if you're going to use `std::vector<double>` in one section of the code, why not use it throughout?  You have:

```
void Analyze()
{
  //...        
  double* x = new double[points]; 
  double* y = new double[points];
 //...
}
```

Unless you've called `delete [] x` and `delete [] y`, this function has a memory leak.  You could have simply used

`std::vector<double> x(points), y(points);`

and in the function to fill them, pass `x.data()` and `y.data()` if using C++11, or if not, `&x[0]` and `&y[0]`.  This alleviates the memory leak.

Even if you did have `delete []` somewhere, if an exception is thrown, that `delete []` may be bypassed, causing a leak.  Using `std::vector`, the `vector` is destroyed even on exception.

---

Second, for the `LocatePulseEdges` function, pass the vector's by (const) reference, not by value.  In addition, there is no need to return the vector by value.  If you were creating a brand new vector within the function, then possibly that would justify the returning of the new vector, but you aren't doing that.  So return a `void`.

```
void LocatePulseEdges(int points, double* signal_x, double* signal_y, double threshold, vector<double>& left_edge, vector<double>& right_edge)
{
    //...
}
```

When you passed the vector by value, a copy of the vector is made, so you're `left_edge.push_back()` call was working with a temporary, not with the actual vector you were passing.  That's why on return, the vector `left_edge` was empty.

---

Last, check for `vector::empty()` if you're going to access the first item in the vector.  You cannot just assume that the item exists in the vector.

```
   LocatePulseEdges(points, x.data(), y.data(), threshold, left, right);
   if ( !left.empty() ) 
       cout << "First left threshold crossing @ time : " << left[0] << endl;
   else
       cout << "No threshold's generated" << endl;
```

The code above assumes you took the advice of using `std::vector<double>` for the `x` and `y` variables.

Answer (score 1):

Pass your left_edge by reference so it can be modified by your fonction :

```
void LocatePulseEdges((int points, double* signal_x, double* signal_y, double threshold, 
std::vector<double> &left_edge, std::vector<double> &right_edge)
{
    //do your stuff
}
```

when you give argument without the `&`, the programm copies the value of your argument and then use it. So you can't modify it. Passing argument with the `&` is called pass by reference.

When you pass an object by reference, you can modify it, and it is faster. If you need to pass an object without modify it, give a const ref :

```
void foo(const std::vector<double> &vec)
```

is faster than

```
void foo(std::vector<double> vec)
```

and prevents you to modify `vec` thanks to the `const` keyword.

Additionnal note :

a `void` function does not require any return, but in many cases its better to do a Bool function

```
Bool LocatePulseEdges()
{
    //do your stuff
    return True ;
}
```

Making it this way allows you to return False prematurly if anything goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Basing on comments I get that:

1. Change LocatePulseEdges function to use reference to:

   `void LocatePulseEdges((int points, double* signal_x, double* signal_y, double threshold, 
   std::vector<double> &left_edge, std::vector<double> &right_edge)
   {
       //do your stuff
   }`

   So you can change value of arguments inside of function
2. Check if element exists in vector before you access it:

   `if (left.size() <= index)
   {
        return left[index];
   }`
3. Now what's wrong with your code. `for (int i=0; i<points; i++)` Is executed, because `points = 9000000`, but `signal_y[i]<threshold` is never true (it's not initialized nowhere in your code), so nothing is inserted to `left`.